# Update the table with one record returned by inner join clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table called tPlayergroup which have columns as:
GroupID, PlayerID, CreatedDTM etc.

I'm using this query:

```
Select top 1 * from tPlayergroup tpg
where tpg.Playerid = 617734
order by tpg.CreatedDTM desc
```

So above query will one record. Now i want to inner join with tTrip(TripID, GroupID, PlayerID) table on PlayerID of both table, making sure that while inner joining tPlayergroup and tTrip should return only one row(**condition should be latest CreatedDTM of tPlayergroup table**) rather than all common data.

How to accomplish it?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What's your definition of a "first match"? Adding a where clause, an order by and a top 1 should give you the tools to get a first match.

Comment: What is t4? There's no t4 in your code. Also, you have to have your destination table referenced in your search condition to issue UPDATE FROM.

Comment: Tables have no inherent order, so you need to give us a rule for how "first" is defined.

Comment: My apology!!!, edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about what are you trying to update exactly, but correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.c2 = t2.c2
FROM t1 
  INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.c1 = t1.c1
  INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.c1 = t1.c1
```

Comment: Hi Nenad,

Thanks for your response, here i want to update t1's c2 column, while inner join t2 and t3 should return only one record.